# difference of performance between MaterialTopTabNavigator and other navigators

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I asked the performance issue of [MaterialTopTabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html). And I found that the performance issue is came from itself not from its screen rendering performance or others.

When I just replace the `MaterialTopTabNavigator` with [`BottomTabNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/bottom-tab-navigator.html), there is no performance issue anymore. i.e, the `BottomTabNavigator` has same screen as `MaterialTopTabNavigator` but much faster than it.

Additionally, when I use `MaterialToptabNavigator` the screen is rendered very slowly. Also, when I use `BottomTabNavigator` the speed of rendering of screen is very fast.

Why the difference is occurred ?

If I change top tab navigator, is there any recommendation ?
Or Is there are any way of solve this problem ?

(I use default configurations. There is no special styles on navigators.)

Comment: Dev build is not a accurate measure to tell that something is slower/faster.Real performance can be tested only in release build.I myself had used MaterialTopTabNavigator and did not face any issues in release build.

Comment: Yes, when I test it in `virtual device`, the speed is better than in `real device`. And as you said the speed can be different in released app. But steel there are speed issue comparing with other navigators and there are several issues in [github issues](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues). But your comment is helpful to understand. Thanks.